# Select specific anchor link with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

I have a menu structure like this:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="parent">
        <a class="menu-link" href="http://url.com/#Id">Id</a>
    </li>
    <li class="parent">
        <a class="menu-link" href="http://url.com/#Id">Id</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and an English version where the menu is like this:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="parent">
        <a class="menu-link" href="http://url.com/en/#Id">Id</a>
    </li>
    <li class="parent">
        <a class="menu-link" href="http://url.com/en/#Id">Id</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Using scrollspy, I’m detecting which section of the page is currently visible. So I can get the Id part of the anchor link. Now how do I select that specific anchor link?

I tried this:

```
$('.menu').find(":contains('#" + this.id"')" ).addClass('active');
```

But that doesn’t work (otherwise I wouldn’t be here!).

Comment: `$('.menu').find("a[href='" + this.id + "']" ).addClass('active');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:contains` will check `html()`/ `text()` part of the anchor tag, you need to use attribute selector for `href` of anchor tag as shown below

```
$('.menu').find("a[href*='#" + this.id + "']" ).addClass('active');
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/keu7k5f7/2/)**

More Information on **[attribute contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)**

Comment: Thank you very much! This is more or less what I tried at first, but I think I forgot the ending quote, and thought it didn’t work. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

what about to separate url (which should be SEO) and set id independent of url query by using data-binding? I hope you are using some template engine to render this html code. If not its ok only one attribute more.

for example:

```
<ul class="menu">
<li class="parent">
    <a class="menu-link" href="http://url.com/en/topic-for-women" data-id="1">Id</a>
</li>
<li class="parent">
    <a class="menu-link" href="http://url.com/en/topic-for-men" data-id="2">Id</a>
</li>
```

For this you can use very simple calling of jquery:

```
$(".menu .menu-link[data-id='2']").addClass("active");
```

here s link [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/8wnkesjb/1/)